How to calculate the forward PE ratio with next year's estimated earnings?
I want to generate a series for forward P/E ratio as: Price / Sum(next 4 quarters earnings).
I am using request.earnings() as follows (it is supposed to deliver future earnings as well?):
ee = request.earnings(syminfo.tickerid, earnings.estimate, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

My intention is to sum the 4 next eps, and then fPE = close / next_year_earnings ; but I am not sure how to do this. So far, I've only used series for historical data.
